# Getting NullPointerException while trying to configure spring boot & posgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am completely new in spring boot and postgres and my application is throwing null pointer exception on running it.

Here is complete code of my application

**application.properties**

```
security.basic.enabled=false
server.port= 9002
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres

spring.datasource.username = postgres
spring.datasource.password = admin
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
# JPA/Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

**DepartmentDao.java**

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class DepartmentDao implements IDepartmentDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Department> getAllDepartments() {
       System.out.println("From Dao");
       String hql = "SELECT c FROM dod.data.entity.DepartmentEntity as c";
       return (List<Department>) entityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList(); // this is line number 34
 }
}
```

There is a controller and service layer in between but issue is not with those layer since i can see console is logging `From Dao`

**DepartmentEntity.java**

```
package dod.data.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
@Entity
@Table(name = "department", schema = "public", catalog = "postgres")
public class DepartmentEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -18211674104610390L;
    private int id;
    private String dept;
    private int empId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "dept", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "emp_id", nullable = false)
    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        DepartmentEntity that = (DepartmentEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (empId != that.empId) return false;
        if (dept != null ? !dept.equals(that.dept) : that.dept != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (dept != null ? dept.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + empId;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Error

```
2017-08-12 22:54:26.572 ERROR 12596 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at dod.data.dao.DepartmentDao.getAllDepartments(DepartmentDao.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at dod.data.service.DepartmentService.getAllDepartments(DepartmentService.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at dod.data.DoddataApplication.test(DoddataApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

I am using intellij & it is connected to postgres. Also I have included the jars required by spring boot.

I followed this [link for spring boot](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-rest-jpa-hibernate-mysql-example) & [this for postgres config](https://www.firstfewlines.com/post/spring-boot-postgresql-database-thymeleaf-gradle-example/). Not sure where I am making mistake.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link to a project on GitHub that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Where NPE is thrown? Entity manager is null? Another thing is, that you could use `JPARepository` - it is much easier to create queries and it provides many methods by itself

Comment: Could you share the DepartmentService.class, I was wondering if DepartmentDao is autowired.

Comment: why downvoting ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate your situation by copying your DepartmentDao code, change a little to mix with the example at [FirstFewLines.com](https://www.firstfewlines.com/post/spring-boot-postgresql-database-thymeleaf-gradle-example/)

I downloaded the entire source code zip file from there, unzipped it, imported into IntelliJ and add this class:

```
package com.firstfewlines.repository;

import com.firstfewlines.domain.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class AnotherRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        System.out.println("From Dao");
        String hql = "SELECT c FROM com.firstfewlines.domain.Student as c";
        return (List<Student>) entityManager.createQuery(hql).getResultList();
    }
}
```

And it is working fine.

If you can share your entire code someway, I can take a look.